# Wrong charset when using include_once('...')

Tags: php, include

I have configured .htaccess file to enable php in .html files. But when I use:

```
include_once('file.php');
```

in a .html file, it includes file.php but with wrong charset - Polish characters aren't displayed correctly (white question marks on black background). In my html file I have this is header:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And I am using include_once somwhere inside body... When I copy content of this php file instead of including the characters are displayed correctly. In my php file I have ONLY html code, not any php functions...

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .php file is not encoded in UTF-8. Open it in an editor and make sure it's saved as UTF-8.